# I am trying to add an image to the layer of contentview of the cell. __bridge id _Nullable vs id. Which one to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add an image to the layer of  contentview of the cell.The code below is working , but I want to know which one is a better practice to follow.

```
self.contentView.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"].CGImage);
```

as suggested by the compiler , or this code

```
self.contentView.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"].CGImage;
```